# Can't connect to external Postgres server from Digitalocean, but works from local computer

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I ssh'd into my Digitalocean droplet (ubuntu 14.04), and tried to connect to my external Postgres server running on RDS, by typing

```
psql -h <host> -p <port> -u <database>
```

into the console.

I got the error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "<host>" (<host ip>) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I tried this on my local computer (Mac), I got prompted for the password, and when I typed it in, a connection was established and everything worked fine.

Please help, as I'm not sure what could be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things could be blocking you here. On the DO droplet side you need to check if you can make outbound connections via the postgres port.

On the postgres server side, you need to ensure the connection user has permissions to connect from the DO droplet IP address. Since it works on your Mac, it is likely you added permission for you Mac to do so previously.

Once you confirm both those sides are good, checking the connectivity between the two. Try running a mtr between the two (one from DO to postgres, and then one from postgres to DO). Check the results to see if any connectivity issues are occurring. If so, identify where they stem from and contact the appropriate host.

Comment: I believe it was a problem with the postgres version that was provided by AWS. I switched to another provider (heroku) and it worked just fine.